# Error when using na.rm = T for ntile() in R

Tags: r

## Summary

I am using R's `ntile()` to assign observations into deciles.

I want `NA`s to be ignored.

However, when I write `na.rm = T`, the function no longer works.

## Code

```r
group_by(date) %>%
mutate(aggregate_ranking = ntile(average_ranking, 10)) %>%
ungroup()
```

## Other

What's most important to me is to assign data into deciles. If it cannot be done via `ntile()`, is there another function that does this where `NA`s are ignored?

## Error message

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `aggregate_ranking`.
x unused argument (na.rm = T)
ℹ Input `aggregate_ranking` is `ntile(average_ranking, 10, na.rm = T)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: date = Jan 1993.
```

Comment: "No longer works" means nothing.  Is there an error message? Unexpected results? What is the input and expected output???

Comment: This is my error message: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `aggregate_ranking`.
x unused argument (na.rm = T)
ℹ Input `aggregate_ranking` is `ntile(average_ranking, 10, na.rm = T)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: date = Jan 1993.

Comment: You need to pass a dataframe to the group_by function.